# Binding ObservableCollection of Custom Objects to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, datacontext

I'm having some trouble binding an `ObservableCollection`  to a `ComboBox` (`RadComboBox`). I used almost the same code before, but now, for some reason, it's not working (nothing shows up in the `ComboBox`).

This is my code for the `ComboBox`:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxServerPropertiesTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding libpm:Collection.Properties}" ItemsSource="{Binding Name}"/>
```

The `DataTemplate` looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxServerPropertiesTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="0 3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="Value:" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Foreground="#FFA2D0FF" Margin="40,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Value}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `Collection()` looks like this:

```
public static class Collection
{
    public static ObservableCollection<ServerProperties.Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

And `ServerPropeties.Property` looks like this:

```
public sealed class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }    
}
```

I tried using `"{Binding Path=libpm:Collection.Properties}"` for both `DataContext` and `ItemSource` and I also tried putting `"{Binding libpm:Collection.Properties}"` for `ItemSource`, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have set the `ItemsSource` to a string property not a collection

Try setting the `ItemsSource` to you collection and use `DisplayMemberPath` to display the `Name` property in the `ComboBox`

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboBoxServerPropertiesTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding libpm:Collection.Properties}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: That throws an exception: `Cannot set both DisplayMemberPath and ItemTemplate.`

Comment: Right, you cannot use DisplayMemberPath if you are using an ItemTemplate. Choose one or the other.